# Is there a way to browse all repositories available to an ubuntu system?

Tags: software-center, repository

Most of the time I come up with a problem, eg "how do I draw a picture in ubuntu?" and then after some googling I come up with a solution eg "get gimp installed" But what if I'm not looking for anything in particular? I just want to browse randomly. I know of the software center, but maybe I'm not using it correctly. Is there a way to make IT display a simple list of every possible app? Is there some web page with them all on it?

Comment: Good question!  Will be valuable to a lot of beginning users!  ;-) (Upvoted!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [apps website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) will show you everything Ubuntu Software Center has with the same categories. All of the below options will generally show you the same results with a 1 line description. You will have a better search if you first decide what category you search fits into though.

From USC ...

[image]

Accesories:

[image]

The 1 line description often is enough to get a basic idea of what the software is about.

And from the [apps website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/):

[image]

Accesories:

[image]

You can also install the old synaptic (that was software we used to use before USC) with

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

The "all" option will list everything, even software that is not in itself is useable on the desktop (like command line utilities or tools software depends on).

[image]

And we also have a website you can search [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for every available release:

[image]

From all of these I do believe the Ubuntu Software Center is the best option if you have your system at hand. If you do not (because you are working on a Windows machine the [apps website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) is a good 2nd option. The synaptic and the packages website method tend to show alot of packages that have no purpose themself but are there to support desktop/server software.

Comment: As usual: good one!  ;-)